# how to convert tag <a to asp:HyperLink control inside listview

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i want to convert tag `<a>` by `asp:HyperLink` control inside listview to get current value of item .

```xml
<asp:ListView ID="ColorListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="ProductColorsDS" OnItemCommand="ColorListView_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsColorsVBPath"].ToString() %><%# Eval("PictureName") %>" class="colorss" rel="enlargeimage" rev="targetdiv:loadarea2,trigger:click,preload:none,fx:fade">
            <asp:Label ID="ColorLabel" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="labelcolor" BackColor='<%# System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Eval("ColorCode").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ColorID") %>' />
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: just add id and runat="server"

Comment: i added id and runat-server already but give me that error
The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: Please post your latest attempt using `asp:HyperLink`; the error you mention describes a syntax error we can only help you detect if we can see the code.

Comment: You cannot use inline blocks (i.e. `<%=..%>`) within attributes of server side controls (with the exception of `<%#...%>'` within template controls).  So that's why you get the error when you add the `id` and `runat` attributes.  if you need it to be server-side then set the `href` in the code-behind instead

Comment: when i added id , server  and replaced href="<%= " by href='<%  ' it work but not load images .
i want to read it because i use it inside second listview that is inside listview also (2 listview)

Comment: `href='<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsColorsVBPath"].ToString()+Eval("PictureName") %>'`

Comment: server tag doesnot contain <% ..... %>

Comment: Yep, as @freefaller says you need to remove those <%= %> blocks. Once you change the <a> to a server control, you'll have to set the href server-side by binding to the OnItemDataBound event.